# How can I mock a property of a class?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, discord.js

This is the class I'm trying to test:

*CommandFactory.ts*

```
import type {ChatInputCommandInteraction} from 'discord.js';
import type CommandInterface from './interfaces/CommandInterface';
import GameCommand from './commands/GameCommand';
import SettingCommand from './commands/SettingCommand';
import SetupCommand from './commands/SetupCommand';
import commands from '@config/commands';

export default class CommandFactory {
    public getCommand(interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction): CommandInterface {
        for (const command of commands) {
            if (command.name === interaction.commandName) {
                if (command.classType === 'SettingCommand') {
                    return new SettingCommand(interaction, command);
                }

                if (command.classType === 'GameCommand') {
                    return new GameCommand(interaction, command);
                }

                if (command.classType === 'SetupCommand') {
                    return new SetupCommand(interaction, command);
                }
            }
        }

        throw new Error(`Unexpected '${interaction.commandName}' command.`);
    }
}
```

And the (not working) test I wrote:

*CommandFactory.test.ts*

```
import CommandFactory from '@components/CommandFactory';
import type {ChatInputCommandInteraction} from 'discord.js';
import type {jest} from '@jest/globals';
import {test, expect} from '@jest/globals';
import GameCommand from '@components/commands/GameCommand';

const interaction: jest.MockedObject<ChatInputCommandInteraction> = {
    commandName: 'add-game',
};

test('Instantiates GameCommand', () => {
    const factory = new CommandFactory();

    const command = factory.getCommand(interaction);

    expect(command).toBeInstanceOf(GameCommand);
});
```

This is the error I receive when running the test:

```
    tests/components/commands/CommandFactory.test.ts:7:7 - error TS2322: Type '{ commandName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MockedObject<ChatInputCommandInteraction<CacheType>>'.
      Type '{ commandName: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ commandType: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput; options: MockedObject<Omit<CommandInteractionOptionResolver<CacheType>, "getMessage" | "getFocused">>; ... 50 more ...; valueOf: MockedFunction<...>; }': commandType, options, inGuild, inCachedGuild, and 46 more.
```

I'm new to Jest and unit testing in general. I want to mock this ChatInputCommandInteraction class and I want to set the value of its property 'commandName' to 'add-game'. Googling got me this far, but I don't really know what to search for.

How do I properly mock an instantiation of a class and alter/set the value of one of its properties?

I'm using Jest and Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy fix you can try, but it depends what else in the dependencies use it is to try:

```js
const interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction = { commandName: 'add-game',} as ChatInputCommandInteraction;
```

Now the long story.

Your factory class is tightly coupled with `commands` and specific command implementations. You can try to isolate one or more of them and test only what is the factory's responsibility.

You can have CommandFactory with a constructor with default values for the `commands` and the commands classes/constructors like this:

```js
// interface which tells the common constructor
type CommandInterfaceConstructor = new (interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction, command: CommandDefinittion) => CommandInterface

const defaultCommandMapping: Map<string, CommandInterfaceConstructor> = new Map([
    ["SettingCommand", SettingCommand],
    ["GameCommand", GameCommand],
    ["SetupCommand", SetupCommand],
])

export default class CommandFactory {
    constructor(
      private commanMap = defaultCommandMapping,
      private configCommands = commands
    ) {}
}
```

then you have to change the logic to use the private CommandFactory injected dependencies

```js
    public getCommand(interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction): CommandInterface {

        const configCommand = this.configCommands.find(x => x.name === interaction.commandName);

        if (configCommand) {
            const Constructor = this.commanMap.get(configCommand.classType);
            if (Constructor) {
                return new Constructor(interaction, configCommand);
            }
        }
        throw new Error(`Unexpected '${interaction.commandName}' command.`);
    }
```

How the test would look like?

```js
class SettingCommandMocked implements CommandInterface {} 
class GameCommandMocked implements CommandInterface {} 
class SetupCommandMocked implements CommandInterface {} 

const testMappings = new Map([
    ["SettingCommand", SettingCommandMocked],
    ["GameCommand", GameCommandMocked],
    ["SetupCommand", SetupCommandMocked],
])


const getInteraction = (commandName: string): ChatInputCommandInteraction => {
    return { commandName } as ChatInputCommandInteraction;
} 

test('Instantiates GameCommand', () => {
    //setup
    // now you have provided mappings yourself
    const factory = new CommandFactory(testMappings);

    //act
    const interaction = getInteraction("add-game");
    const command = factory.getCommand(interaction);

    //assert
    expect(command).toBeInstanceOf(GameCommandMocked);
});
```